# c++ pointer void function issue

Tags: c++, function, pointers, void

Just started with c++ have done some coding in java and python but keep getting an error:

non-standard syntax; use'&' to create a pointer to member

tried changing the code several time and could not fix issue.  the issue is with the void setRadius in my main function.

***circleType.h***

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class circleType {
private:
    double radius;
public:
    circleType();
    void setRadius();
    double getRadius();
};
```

***circle.cpp***

```
circleType::circleType() {}

void circleType::setRadius() {
    cout << "what is the radius of your circle:  ";
    cin >> radius;
}

double circleType::getRadius() {
    cout << "your radius is: " << radius << endl;
    return radius;
}

int main() {
    circleType circle;
    circleType::setRadius;
    double radius = circle.getRadius;
    return 0;
}
```

***edit***

Solved, simple syntax error - this solved my problem.

```
circle.setRadius();
double radius = circle.getRadius();
```

Comment: Where's the pointer?

Comment: circle.setRadius(); double radius = circle.getRadius(); And wherever you are learning C++ from, learn it from somewhere else.

Comment: Remove the second line.  Third line of `main()` needs to be `circle.getRadius()`.   Without the `()`, both lines (ostensibly) try to evaluate the address of the member function, rather than calling it, and the correct way of doing that is using an `&` like the compiler says.

Comment: That, too. Because it doesn't add anything useful to the question. But you do get voted down for posting a poor question. It fails to provide a [mcve], and never even explains, what the issue is. See [ask] to fix this.

Comment: You get voted down for a few reasons: 1) You don't ask a specific question. 2) You don't include the exact error message or tell us what you're trying to do when you get it. (Compile? Link? Execute?). 3) You don't simplify your code to the minimum necessary to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
circleType::setRadius;
double radius = circle.getRadius;
```

The first line doesn't do anything. The second line tries to set a variable of type `double` equal to a function. Perhaps you want to *call* these functions?

This is what non-operator member function calls look like in C++:

```
double area = circle.areaCir(radius);
double circumferance = circle.circumCir(radius);
circle.printCir(circumferance, area);
```

So try this:

```
circle.setRadius();
double radius = circle.getRadius();
```

Comment: The first line is actually the reason for the compiler error the OP asked about.  Saying it doesn't do anything is incorrect - it is invalid syntax.